# jQuery nestable - save to MySQL with PHP nested set model

Tags: php, mysql, tree, nested

I use now Nestable plugin for eshop categories http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/

I save data to MySQL database with columns `parent_id, order, level` using the [**Nested Set model**](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

But I would like to use nested model only with columns `lft, rgt`

Could you please gave me example how to save data to database or is there any wrapper which can I use to just insert new item, update all tree and delete one item, using the **Nested Set model**?

---

I found Baobab library http://www.sideralis.org/baobab/, which do these operations, but it's very heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here...

**To Insert:**

```
begin;
SELECT rgt INTO new_lft FROM tree_map WHERE node_id = parent_id;
UPDATE tree_map SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= new_lft;
UPDATE tree_map SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > new_lft;
INSERT INTO tree_map (lft, rgt, parent_id) VALUES (new_lft, (new_lft + 1), parent_id);
commit;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

**To delete:**

```
SELECT lft, rgt, (rgt - lft), (rgt - lft + 1), parent_id 
  INTO new_lft, new_rgt, has_leafs, width, superior_parent 
  FROM tree_map WHERE node_id = pnode_id;

begin;
DELETE FROM tree_content WHERE node_id = pnode_id;

IF (has_leafs = 1) THEN
  DELETE FROM tree_map WHERE lft BETWEEN new_lft AND new_rgt;
  UPDATE tree_map SET rgt = rgt - width WHERE rgt > new_rgt;
  UPDATE tree_map SET lft = lft - width WHERE lft > new_rgt;
ELSE
  DELETE FROM tree_map WHERE lft = new_lft;
  UPDATE tree_map SET rgt = rgt - 1, lft = lft - 1, parent_id = superior_parent 
   WHERE lft BETWEEN new_lft AND new_rgt;
  UPDATE tree_map SET rgt = rgt - 2 WHERE rgt > new_rgt;
  UPDATE tree_map SET lft = lft - 2 WHERE lft > new_rgt;
END IF;
commit;
```

You might also want to use amazing stored procedure for MySQL instead:

https://github.com/werc/TreeTraversal/blob/master/sql/r_tree_traversal.sql#L4